# System backup in case of attack?

Tags: webserver, mysql, ddos

My system will be running for a well known insurance company within the UK, it will hold and process a lot of information for claims, brakdowns etc etc.

I am worried that the company and the site as the site needs to be accesses externally by brokers will be a target for DDoS.

Is there anything I can do within the code that will backup all data if a DDoS attack happens on the server?

I have a feeling I'll just get 'no' or 'yes' answers here if this is the case the what additional security can I put in place to try and prevent DDoS attacks?

Comment: If you don't do backups already, you have no business serving an insurance company.

Comment: I do system backups, I just want to know if there is a way to do lets say an 'emergency backup' so as soon as the server detects an attack it backs up all data

Comment: Look into HA setups (which is high availability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backups don't really have anything to do with preventing or mitigating DDOS attacks. A DDOS attack will prevent people from accessing your site, it doesn't have anything to do with the destruction of data.

So to answer your question, no - I don't think setting up backups will help you in the event of a DDOS attack.  That said, regularly backing up data should be a standard task in any software environment so make sure you are doing that.  In addition to backing up the data - do a mock restore so you will be familiar with the process to bring everything back up after a disaster.

If you are concerned about DDOS give [this post a read](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/how-do-major-sites-prevent-ddos) - it has some excellent information on handling DDOS.